# Angular: Compile is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been facing an issue for long time. Can you please help me out on this.
Actually, I want to use table directive in many places. so I have created a directive and binds angular UI grid into it. But I'm getting compile error.

> Error: angular.min.js:102 ReferenceError: compile is not defined

**But  I could load the grid content**

What I did wrong here?

```
HTML
<div ng-controller="ctrl1 as two">
    <ltcg-table><ltcg-table>    
</div>
<div ng-controller="ctrl2 as two">
    <ltcg-table><ltcg-table>    
</div>

JS

myApp.directive('ltcgTable', function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,       
                replace: false,                            
                scope: {  },
                controller: Controller,
                controllerAs: 'Controller',
                bindToController: true,            
                compile: compile   
            }

        });
```

Comment: I don't know what will it do but use `compile: $compile `, instead of `compile: compile `.

Comment: Thanks. but while using compile: $compile getting error angular.min.js:102 Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/multidir?p0=ltcgTable&p1=uiGrid…p3=%3Cltcg-table%20ui-grid%3D%22gridOptions%22%20class%3D%22ng-scope%22%3E

Answer (score 0):

the `compile` function (second part of `compile: compile`) is not defined. It should be a function in the form of:

```
function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) { ... }
```

So try defining the directive like so:

```
myApp.directive('ltcgTable', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,       
        replace: false,                            
        scope: {  },
        controller: Controller,
        controllerAs: 'Controller',
        bindToController: true,            
        compile: function(tElement, tAttr, transclude) {
            //do some stuff here
        }   
    }

});
```

Or, alternatively, if you don't need to do anything special and the grid works as it is, just leave the `compile` field out of the direction specification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But no luck when I use compile function I'm getting an error "angular.min.js:102 Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/multidir?p0=ltcgTable&p1=uiGrid&p2=transclusion&p3=%3Cltcg-table%20ui-grid%3D%22gridOptions%22%3E"

Comment: Do you really need transclude to be true? Do you really need the compile function? Do you really need a directive scope? If not, leave these fields out of the directive configuration.

Comment: Yes, I need scope for isolate because I want reuse this directive.

Comment: Have you tried using `link` method instead of `compile`? What is your objective? What do you want in place of `<ltcg-table><ltcg-table>`?

Comment: Actually, I want to load angular UI grid in <ltcg-table> directive. So I can reuse this directive other places with difference content.